# Multi-player "LAN" games via OpenVPN with 3 players or more

Tags: windows-10, openvpn, lan, gaming

We (my friends and me) have the following problems:

We have an own OpenVPN server on Debian Linux. This is configured properly, the VPN works like a charm. But if we join together and want to play some multi-players games in "LAN" (using the OpenVPN) then we can't play multi-player "LAN" games if we are 4 players or more present at the same time.

We all have Windows 10. If we are only 2 players, then it works without any problems. If we are 3 players, then sometimes we have that problem, but most of times it works (we see each other's games). From 4 players we have always that problem, which is: 1-2 players see each other's LAN games, but 1 or 2 players are always not seeing it.

Firewall is set properly (without it also 2 or 3 players would not be able to play the game together). Also the server is running. No error can be seen in the server's log. Also the clients' Windows event logs do not contain any related errors.

What may be the solution? What should we try to have a stable multi-playable "LAN" using OpenVPN for 3 and more players?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your OpenVPN setup is configured to be routed rather than bridged. To make all machines appear as if they were on a LAN, you will need to configure OpenVPN into bridged mode.

You can find more details on this here:
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/determining-whether-to-use-a-routed-or-bridged-vpn/